# Program running in debug mode in C::B only

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks, fopen

I am currently writing a program which at some point needs to store the sizes of all the files in a specific folder in an array. My program crashes when running it on Code::Blocks in release mode, but does run in debug mode. It also runs without any problems on XCode on Mac OS. Here's the code:

```
#define MALLOC_ERROR -1
#define DIR_ACCESS_ERROR -2
#define FILE_ACCESS_ERROR -3
#define FILE_OPEN_ERROR -4
#define OUTPUT_FILE_OPEN_ERROR -5

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int compare(const void*, const void*);
int getFileSizeMarginNumbers(char[], int, unsigned long int*);

int main(void){

    FILE *out;
    int n;
    int i, count = 1;
    unsigned long int *fileSizeMarginNumber;
    char directoryName[] = "C:\\Users\\Борис\\Desktop\\new\\";
    char outputFilePath[] = "C:\\Users\\Борис\\Desktop\\out.txt";

    printf("Enter number of files in directory:");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (!(fileSizeMarginNumber = (unsigned long int*)malloc(n*sizeof(unsigned long int)))){
        printf("Not enough memory");
        return MALLOC_ERROR;
    }
    switch (getFileSizeMarginNumbers(directoryName, n, fileSizeMarginNumber)) {
        case MALLOC_ERROR:
            return MALLOC_ERROR;
            break;

        case DIR_ACCESS_ERROR:
            return DIR_ACCESS_ERROR;
            break;

        case FILE_ACCESS_ERROR:
            return FILE_ACCESS_ERROR;
            break;

        case FILE_OPEN_ERROR:
            return FILE_OPEN_ERROR;
            break;
    }

    qsort(fileSizeMarginNumber, n, sizeof(unsigned long int), compare);

    if (!(out = fopen(outputFilePath, "w"))){
        printf("Unable to open output file");
        return OUTPUT_FILE_OPEN_ERROR;
    }

    for (i=1; i<n; ++i) {
        if (fileSizeMarginNumber[i] == fileSizeMarginNumber[i - 1])
            ++count;
        else{
            fprintf(out, "%ldKB - %ldKB: %d file(s);\n", (fileSizeMarginNumber[i - 1] - 1)*16, fileSizeMarginNumber[i - 1]*16, count);
            count = 1;
        }
    }

    fprintf(out, "%ldKB - %ldKB: %d files;\n", (fileSizeMarginNumber[i - 1] - 1)*16, fileSizeMarginNumber[i - 1]*16, count);

    return 0;
}

int getFileSizeMarginNumbers(char directoryName[], int n, unsigned long int *fileSizeMarginNumber){

    int i, fileDescriptor;
    struct dirent *file;
    struct stat currentSize;
    DIR *directory;
    FILE *buf;

    if (!(directory = opendir(directoryName))) {
        printf("Unable to get access to the specified directory");
        return DIR_ACCESS_ERROR;
    }

    for (i=0;i<2;++i){
        if (!(file = readdir(directory))) {
            printf("Unable to get access to a file in the specified directory");
            return FILE_ACCESS_ERROR;
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        if (!(file = readdir(directory))) {
            printf("Unable to get access to a file in the specified directory");
            return FILE_ACCESS_ERROR;
        }
        printf("%s", strcat(strdup(directoryName), file->d_name));
        if (!(buf = fopen(strcat(strdup(directoryName), file->d_name), "r"))){
            printf("Unable to process a file in the specified directory");
            return FILE_OPEN_ERROR;
        }

        fileDescriptor = fileno(buf);
        fstat(fileDescriptor, &currentSize);
        fileSizeMarginNumber[i] = (unsigned long int)truncl(currentSize.st_size/(1024*16)) + 1;

        fclose(buf);
    }

    return 0;
}

int compare(const void *a, const void *b){

    if ((*(long int*)a - *(long int*)b) < 0)
        return -1;
    else if ((*(long int*)a - *(long int*)b) == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

The problem seems to be located in the following block:

```
for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        if (!(file = readdir(directory))) {
            printf("Unable to get access to a file in the specified directory");
            return FILE_ACCESS_ERROR;
        }
        printf("%s", strcat(strdup(directoryName), file->d_name));
        if (!(buf = fopen(strcat(strdup(directoryName), file->d_name), "r"))){
            printf("Unable to process a file in the specified directory");
            return FILE_OPEN_ERROR;
        }

        fileDescriptor = fileno(buf);
        fstat(fileDescriptor, &currentSize);
        fileSizeMarginNumber[i] = (unsigned long int)truncl(currentSize.st_size/(1024*16)) + 1;

        fclose(buf);
    }
```

The program is supposed to open all files in a folder step-by-step. However, the second or third call to fopen sometimes triggers the following exception:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In ntdll!RtlLargeIntegerToChar () (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll)
```

I do not understand this dependency on where I am running my program and I would've been very grateful for your help.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `strcat()` in `fopen()` is not correct:

```
strcat(strdup(directoryName), file->d_name)
```

First `strdup()` allocates `strlen(directoryName)+1` bytes and copies `directoryName` then `strcat()` wants to append `file->d_name` to that copy. But as there is no extra space allocated a seg fault might occur. Do something like that instead:

```
char *pathname = MALLOC( strlen(directoryName) + strlen(file->d_name) + 1 );
strcpy( pathname, directoryName );
strcat( pathname, file->d_name );
```

And don't forget to `free(pathname)` when you don't need it any more

Comment: Oh my God, I was too busy finding some complicated issue with fopen that I didn't even bother to think about proper memory allocation. Thank you very much!